# utility applications in Iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

What are utility applications & how to use them in Iphone?

How to start with utility application implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The utility app template is a template which is useful for apps which require fairly simple user interaction by default.  Here is the definition from the Apple Getting Started guide.  I hope that helps.

> "Utility Application. An application that implements a main view and lets the user access a flip-side view to perform simple customizations. The Stocks application is an example of a utility application."

You might find this example useful as an example:

http://wh1t3s.com/2010/05/27/iphone-utility-app-with-eaglview-on-flipside/